# writing a string every n milliseconds

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to write a simple win32 console application in C to simulate stock price ticks, I need to specify the time interval so that every n milliseconds a new price is published.

The end goal is to write test data to a database and stress test an application which is supposed to react to new ticks and perform calcs.

My simple price server will be structured as follows

```
int main (void)
{
    int n = 0;

    //set interval to 1 millisecond

    while (true) {

        printf ("New price...\n");

        //  Publish price and write to database

        SleepExecution (n);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have not been able to find an API call which will allow me to stop the execution of the above code for the arbitrary n milliseconds. Sleep looks to be the solution but I would prefer not to use it.

Are there any libraries you would recommend using or samples on the web I could draw inspiration from?

Comment: Why do you not want to use sleep? If you explain this, people are more likely to recommend suitable alternatives.

Comment: I guess you have four choices: 1) Use sleep, 2) Use a library that uses sleep, 3) Implement your own sleep (requires detailed crap at the system level, not recommended) or 4) Use a library that implemented their own sleep. 1) Is by FAR the easiest.

Comment: @glowcoder: I think your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @Catcall unfortunately not every piece of wisdom is an answer. The specific question is recommended libraries or samples, and I have none.

Comment: Granularity seems to be the real problem. Even nanosleep() "can take up to 10 ms longer than specified until the process becomes runnable again". (http://linux.die.net/man/2/nanosleep) Might need a real-time OS for a consistent 1 ms. (Or 10 concurrent processes running at 10 ms intervals.)

Comment: As an aside, what you really want for a load generator is to set the frequency with which messages are sent. This means that you need to combine a `Sleep()` or better, with `GetTickCount()` or better, so that you allow for the execution time of the message send.

Comment: Why are you trying to get precise timing of updates?  You're simulating stock prices changes, which will be reported over the network.  You should expect considerable latency and jitter from the network, so shouldn't your simulator have similar characteristics?

Comment: @richardolsson. I do not wish to use sleep() as this is the easy solution! The high frequency domain is new to me and I am trying to peel off the various layers of complexity associated with capture, storage and usage of sub second frequency updates. My first goal is to create a data generator that allows me to reliably generate data at any frequency I specify. The second step is to rifle the data across the network and measure delays, latency, etc. Hopefully at this point I will be able to understand where bottlenecks are occurring. Granularity control is very important

Answer (score 2):

`CreateWaitableTimer` is great for running code periodically.  Combined with `timeBeginPeriod` to increase the system timer rate, and turning up your thread priority so it wakes on time, you should have a solution that's 99.99% effective.

Answer (score 1):

Suspending execution is an operating system-specific operation.

For MS Windows (Win 95 and after), use the function `Sleep()` where the parameter is the minimum rescheduling time in milliseconds.

<s>For Linux, there are several ways, but `int nanosleep(const struct timespec *req, struct timespec *rem);` allows nanosecond precision for most uses.  `sleep()` allows one second precision, so it probably isn't useful for your purposes.</s>

---

I see that win32 was mentioned.  To use `Sleep()`, the program can probably use a constant value, depending on the requirements, but if high consistency is required, then dynamically compute the delay based on how much longer it is until the next time a update is needed.